# is there a way to highlight default component in CSS until another one is clicked

Tags: html, css, angular

```
.pill-nav a:focus{
    background-color: black;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
  <div class="pill-nav">
    <a routerLink='dcp'>
      Programs
    </a>
```

here I need the programs tab highlighted until another one is clicked on which is why I used focus but then this does not highlight it by default when the page is opened

Answer (score 1):

I am not much familiar with Angular but if you can access DOM then the focus() method seems fine to me

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();
```

```css
.pill-nav a:focus{
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pill-nav">
    <a href='#'>
      Programs
    </a>
 </div>
 <a href="#">Another One</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus will change as soon as the user clicks somewhere so this isn't a great idea.

Your best bet is to use the RouterLinkActive attribute. This defines class(es) that should be added to the link if it points to the current URL.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

```
.pill-nav a.active{
    background-color: black;
}
<a routerLink='dcp' routerLinkActive='active'>
   Programs
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thanks for the help, I did use routerLinkAcitve but it dint work as it was on my code, but when I changed it to a list using < ul > tag and < li > it worked just fine thankyou

```
.pill-nav a:focus{
    background-color: black;
}
.active a{
  background-color: black;
}

li{
  display: inline;
}
ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
      <div class="pill-nav">
        <ul>
          <li routerLinkActive="active">
            <a routerLink='dcp' >
              <P>Programs</P> 
             </a>
          </li>
```